# Проект на PyQt5

Tags: python, qt

Делаю проект на Python, сборник шифров. Но возникла проблема, Переменные выделяются желтым и пишет Unexpected argument. Как это исправить? Ошибка: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, попытаться запустить и заменить в вопросе изображение полным текстом ошибки, которую выдаст. Во-вторых, показать код метода `rot13`.

Comment: Добавил, извиняюсь за кривоту.

Comment: Текстом, не изображениями.

Comment: def rot13(self, message):
        message = list(message.upper())
        for symbol in range(len(message)):
            message[symbol] = chr(ord(message[symbol]) % 26 + ord('A'))
        return "".join(message)

Comment: Только rot13 находится в другом файле, в классе. Но я его импортирую. Могу Прислать файлы.

Comment: c rot13 уже заработало, только еще некоторые не работают